# Mailto link not copying body of email on Chromebook

Tags: javascript, gmail, mailto, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm generating a `mailto:` link that also contains the body of an email. I'm opening the link using JavaScript to launch the `mailto:` client of the OS. On Chromebooks the link opens Gmail with the email address, but not the body of the email. This is the link:

```
var MailToLink = 'mailto:test@test.com?subject=Test%20Email%20Subject&body=Great,%20the%20mailto%20protocol%20works%20and%20you%27re%20good%20to%20go.%20Good%20luck.'
```

This is the line I use to open the link: `window.open(MailToLink, '_blank');`

It works just fine on Windows 10 OS with Thunderbird and Gmail for Android.

Is there something I need to change for Chromebooks?

Comment: using anything but _self creates fork bomb for my beta channel chromebook, but with _self the body shows up (with a little delay) for me. I would test with _self to make sure its not an interaction with popup/security features. But also you can try deleting gmail from chrome://settings/handlers and record the unhandled url in the broken tab it creates before letting gmail reregister to see which stage is dropping the body.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and let you know how this works.

Comment: @frenchie any updates on how lossleader's solution went?

Comment: On Monday I will

Comment: The problem is that _self doesn't work in terms of UX. The email needs to be processed in another tab with the current tab not changing URL.

Comment: Does rearranging the parameters in the `mailto` link provide any different results?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that (some) Chromebooks don't have a great processing power. So, it might not be possible and if it is possible, I wouldn't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Please tell use why the javascript is needed and not a `<a>`  and could the user click on a link/button before creating the email?

Answer (score 3):

What about setting `location.href` instead of creating a popup?

```js
location.href = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=Test%20Email%20Subject&body=Great,%20the%20mailto%20protocol%20works%20and%20you%27re%20good%20to%20go.%20Good%20luck."
```

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

Good to know is that subject and body in mailto links are described in [RFC 2368 - The mailto URL scheme](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html)

> Clients that
>      resolve mailto URLs into mail messages should be able to correctly
>      create RFC 822-compliant mail messages using the "subject" and "body"
>      headers.

Please also note there is a paragraph over "unsafe headers" - so I think the content could be also important.

> 4. Unsafe headers
>
>    The user agent interpreting a mailto URL SHOULD choose not to create
>      a message if any of the headers are considered dangerous; it may also
>      choose to create a message with only a subset of the headers given in
>      the URL.  Only the Subject, Keywords, and Body headers are believed
>      to be both safe and useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var MailToLink = 'mailto:test@test.com?subject=Test%20Email%20Subject&body=Great,%20the%20mailto%20protocol%20works%20and%20you%27re%20good%20to%20go.%20Good%20luck.'
var sendEmail = document.getElementById('sendEmail');

  sendEmail.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    window.location.href = MailToLink;
  });
```

```html
<input type="button" id="sendEmail" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Another stable option is to a `<a>` and edit the `href` with javascript.

e.g.

```js
var mailto = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=Test%20Email%20Subject&body=Great,%20the%20mailto%20protocol%20works%20and%20you%27re%20good%20to%20go.%20Good%20luck."

document.getElementById("myLink").setAttribute("href", mailto)
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <a id="myLink">Create email now!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure if this fits in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do might be to use the classic mail to link using an anchor tag, however, I am guessing you are using JavaScipt for a specific reason so maybe if you specify a simple name as the second argument rather than one of the '_blank' or '_self' values. for example, you could call it **'emailWindow'** or something like that.

Here is the is the MDN link that inspired using the window name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Parameters

and here is some code below to test it out.

*Note: For security reasons I believe StackOverflow has disabled the ability to open a new window so you will have to test the button code locally, sorry

```js
var MailToLink = 'mailto:test@test.com?subject=Test%20Email%20Subject&body=Great,%20the%20mailto%20protocol%20works%20and%20you%27re%20good%20to%20go.%20Good%20luck.'

const sendEmailButton = document.getElementById('sendEmailButton');
sendEmailButton.onclick = () => {
    window.open(MailToLink, 'emailWindow');
    if (window.open && !window.closed) {window.close();}
};
```

```html
<h1>Anchor Tag and Button Versions of Mail To</h1>

<h2>The anchor tag version</h2>
<a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=Test%20Email%20Subject&body=Great,%20the%20mailto%20protocol%20works%20and%20you%27re%20good%20to%20go.%20Good%20luck.">test mail to using href</a>


<h2>the button version</h2>
<button type="button" id="sendEmailButton">test mail to using button</button>
```